# Stored procedure as a data source in ML.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ml.net

is there a way I can pass stored procedure data in DatabaseSource.

Any other way I can load data from stored procedures in ML.net?

```
var loader = context.Data.
CreateDatabaseLoader<Patient>();

var SPData=(mySPData);

DatabaseSource dbSource =SPData;

IDataView data= loader.Load(dbSource);
```

Comment: About halfway down this page you'll see a sample of extracting data from SQL Server. https://dev.to/icebeam7/building-a-machine-learning-model-with-sql-server-ml-net-and-c-374a try replacing `Select CAST(Id as REAL) as Id, ......` with `EXEC MyStoredProc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to as long as you can express it in your query.

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/load-data-ml-net

One other way to do it would be to execute a query with your stored procedure and map the results to an `IEnumerable<T>`. Then, load the IEnumerable into an `IDataView`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/load-data-ml-net#load-data-from-other-sources